# How to parse json object from string line?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm new to logstash. I would like to parse every line in log file as json object using **grok**. My log looks like this:

```
1570519737247 I access {"date":"2019-10-08T09:28:57.247","rootTitle":"title1","rootModel":"model1","dcTitle":"[1a]"}
1570519737247 I access {"date":"2019-10-08T09:28:57.247","rootTitle":"title2","rootModel":"model2","dcTitle":"[1b]"}
```

You can see that every line is starting with text and then there is valid json object.

And I want to construct object for every line that would look like this:

```
{
    "accesing": "1570519737247",
    "message": {
        "date":"2019-10-08T09:28:57.247",
        "rootTitle":"title1",
        "rootModel":"model1",
        "dcTitle":"[1a]"
        }
}
```

So I want to take the number at the beggining and assign it to "accesing" key, I dont need the "I access" word, then the json object to "message".

I tried this pattern in grok debugger %{WORD:accesing} %{GREEDYDATA:message} but of course thats not what i need. Please, can anybody help?

Comment: And after the grok filter, as shown in Ishara's answer, you can use the json filter to parse the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
%{WORD:accesing} I access %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

**input:**

```
1570519737247 I access {"date":"2019-10-08T09:28:57.247","rootTitle":"title1","rootModel":"model1","dcTitle":"[1a]"}
```

**output:**

```
{
  "accesing": [
    [
      "1570519737247"
    ]
  ],
  "message": [
    [
      "{"date":"2019-10-08T09:28:57.247","rootTitle":"title1","rootModel":"model1","dcTitle":"[1a]"}"
    ]
  ]
}
```